# delete slash from variable

Tags: shell, syntax, tar

With help, i have this script but i am not sure how i get rid of "./" from the variable so i can zip the folder. Please can you advise me.

thanks
Nick

```
#/bin/sh
BASEDIR=/tmp/

cd $BASEDIR
find . -type d | sort > newfiles.txt
DIFF=$(comm -13 oldfiles.txt newfiles.txt)
echo $DIFF
if [ "$DIFF" != "" ]
then
    #echo "A new dir is found"
   tar -czvf "$DIFF".tar.gz --verbose
fi

mv newfiles.txt oldfiles.txt
```

failed output:

```
+ tar -czvf ./file2.tar.gz --verbose
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: Its not sure what you try to archive, please be more specific... ATM you first try to create a column of filenames and paths via `comm -13` and then you try to use this column to create archives ? Is your goal to create archives for each folder or all in one ?

Comment: @Cyrus: since you removed tag 'bash', you should probably add tag 'shell' instead.

Comment: @Maxxim: I think this is a useful hint. I have done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stems from this command:

```
tar -czvf "$DIFF".tar.gz --verbose
```

You specify the archive name, but not the files/folders to be added to said archive.

You would need it to change to:

```
tar -czvf "$DIFF".tar.gz "$DIFF"
```

Note that you don't need `--verbose` since you already specified `-v` with `-czvf`.

---

**However**, your code won't work like intended if `DIFF` contains multiple items (i.e. lines). You probably want something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
BASEDIR="/tmp/"

cd "$BASEDIR"
find . -type d | sort > newfiles.txt
DIFF=$(comm -13 oldfiles.txt newfiles.txt)
echo "$DIFF"
IFS=$'\n'
for item in $DIFF
do
    #echo "A new dir is found"
   tar -czvf "$item.tar.gz" "$item"
done

mv newfiles.txt oldfiles.txt
```

---

That being said, if you want to remove `./` from `find` output, you can use:

```
find . -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > newfiles.txt
```

but you don't actually have to do this for your script to work.

Comment: Hi, using the "-printf "%P\n" for clarity, the script does not work? It does not find the new folder?

Comment: @nick: not all versions of `find` support `-printf` with all possible tokens. What OS are you on?

Comment: "Oracle Linux Server 7.6"

Comment: @nick: check `man find` to see if `-printf` is supported and which `%` tokens are supported

Comment: it does exist -- printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

Comment: SYNOPSIS ----
       find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]

Comment: checked  man pages and as per above it is

Comment: %p     File's name.

              %P     File's name with the name of the command line argument  under  which  it  was  found
                     removed.

Comment: @nick: so it is supported. Test `find . -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort` manually on the command line. If it works there, it should work within the script too. Works fine for me.

Comment: It did not work earlier as there were no new folders created. You have been an immense help. Bless u bro